# Update unique table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

Hello i have this table.

```
ADDR      | STATE  |  ID 
CRA.20 15 |  REP   |  (null)
CRA.20 15 |  REP   |  (null)
CRA.20 15 |  REP   |   (null)
CRA.20 15 |  PRI   |   RR_88_JK
```

I need transform this table ..

```
ADDR      | STATE |   ID 
CRA.20 15 |  REP  |   RR_88_JK
CRA.20 15 |  REP  |   RR_88_JK
CRA.20 15 |  REP  |   RR_88_JK
CRA.20 15 |  PRI  |   RR_88_JK
```

I have this QRY but not function. You have a one idea?.

```
UPDATE TABLE_A A
   SET a.ID = b.ID
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT b.ID
              FROM TABLE_A B
             WHERE a.ADDR = B.ADDR  AND b.STATE = 'PRI')
 and  A.STATE = 'REP';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a subquery to set the value:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A A
   SET a.ID = (SELECT b.ID
               FROM TABLE_A B
               WHERE a.ADDR = B.ADDR AND b.STATE = 'PRI' AND rownum = 1
              )
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.ID
                 FROM TABLE_A B
                 WHERE a.ADDR = B.ADDR AND b.STATE = 'PRI'
                ) AND
         A.STATE = 'REP';
```

`B` is only known in the subquery, not in the outer query.

Comment: Hello I use this qry but not function. ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row. I understand this qry but not meeting this error.

Comment: @SantiagoEspitia . . . Obviously, you have some `addr` values that have two or more `'pri'` rows.   The `and rownum = 1` arbitrarily chooses one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A A
   SET a.ID = (SELECT MIN(ID)
                 FROM TABLE_A
                 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL AND
                       STATE = 'PRI')
   WHERE ID IS NULL AND
         STATE = 'REP'
```

Best of luck.